# Query for Trimming the date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, trim

I've been asked to write a query to get all the automatic entries that were placed 1 day before the current day.  However, the problem is that the date is in this format and I cannot alter the database.

E.g. 20130329.134405990

I'm not sure how I would do this.  I was thinking I trim it to the first 8 digits and then minus the current day by 1 day.  I'm not sure how the code would look though, can anyone make any suggestions to my existing code?  That would be greatly appreciated

Existing Query:
select * from JnlDB 
where UserCode = 'Automation';

Comment: What database are you using?  (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, ...)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm testing the query on two different databases: sql oracle developer and microsoft sql server management studio.

Comment: Looks like a nightmare! I'd highly recommend that you use database functions to subtract a day from the current date - saves worrying about whether there a 31, 30 or 28 days in the month, leap years, random alpha particles etc. etc.

Comment: @KJ, what is the datatype of the column that keeps the date information?

Comment: Its numeric and 17 digits.

Comment: @nurdglaw can you show me how that would look like in a statement please? Where Date = ..

Comment: There's already a couple of answers showing that, one each for SQL Server and Oracle

Comment: @nurdglaw their not working correctly.  I want to be able to run this query everyday to get the data for the previous day so I can send it out as a report.

Comment: I think the suggestion is that you apply the techniques to find the date for yesterday, then write a query against your database using the calculated "yesterday's date" in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get one day before your current date (SQL SERVER):

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())
```

I think it would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE LEFT(CAST(datefield AS VARCHAR(25)),8) = CAST(DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(25))
```

Update, wasn't comparing to today as you requested.

Comment: I tried running the second query, but no data is being shown when I run it.  No errors are coming but no data either.

Comment: I wasn't paying attention, updated answer to compare to current date.

Comment: No, its one table. It's just that the database has thousands of entries that are inputted either automatically or by a user all on different dates.  What I'm interested in is just getting those automated entries for the one day before the current day, so I can e-mail them to the appropriate parties making them aware of all the automative changes that have occurred.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Still displaying an empty database with no errors.. How would I get this query to work on the Oracle SQL Developer thats connected to the SQL Database? Because that is the application used to create reports from this query.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head:
 You could run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM JnlDB WHERE UserCode = 'Automation' AND     
SUBSTR(ENTEREDDATE,1,8)=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'YYYYMMDD');
```

This will work on Oracle.

In SQL Server though:

```
 SELECT * FROM JnlDB WHERE UserCode = 'Automation' AND     
 CONVERT(VARCHAR,LEFT(ENTEREDDATE,8))=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112)
```

I'm sure there's a better, more performant way of doing this in SQL Server but I've been away from it for long.

Comment: It is a nvar value though not a string, is there any way around this?

Comment: It says this when I run it in Oracle SQL Developer: 'SUBSTR' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Nvar? Maybe nchar or nvarchar?

Comment: It says "DATE (numeric(17,9), not null)" so not a string

Comment: Weird.Do you connect to Oracle or some other RDBMS with ORacle SQL Developer? SUBSTR is a built in Oracle function without which I wouldn't survive. I use it all the time.

Comment: My boss wants me to write the query in Oracle SQL Developer but I'm connecting to an SQL database not an Oracle database.  I hope you can help me solve my problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer for SQL Server. Check it up. It should work, I tested on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TableName
 WHERE the_date >= CAST(CONVERT(Varchar, DateDiff(day, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 112) AS Int) 
   AND the_date <  CAST(CONVERT(Varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 112) AS Int)
```

In Oracle:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableName
 WHERE the_date >= CAST(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1, 'YYYYMMDD') AS Int)
   AND the_date < CAST(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD) AS Int)
```

I know it's not much for readibility, but it'll do the trick...